# ServiceStack.Text strange behavior while deserializing nullable boolean

Tags: .net, json, servicestack, json-deserialization, servicestack-text

Suppose I have a class containing a member with `bool?` type.

```
public class Request
{
    public bool? IsOk {get; set;}
}
```

I expect ServiceStack's JSON deserializer that any values other than `true` or `false` in a JSON string result in `null` for this member.
But sometimes it results in `false`, and sometimes it results in `null`!

There is a sample code in [gistlyn](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=4443d0dbfab92c819d4cb5d043c22bf4) that shows this issue.

Why does this happen? Is there any configuration to force strict parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default ServiceStack's Text serializers tries to deserialize as much as possible without error. You can set `JsConfig.ThrowOnError=true;` (or `Env.Strict=true` in [latest v5.1.1+ on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget)) if you want the JSON Serializer to throw on deserialization error.

Or you can instead log any serialization errors to the console with:

```
Tracer.Instance = new ConsoleTracer();
```

The difference in behavior is that due to popular conventions values such as `1`, `"1"` and `"on"` are also treated as `true` any other <2 characters are treated as `false`. Any other string value tries to deserialize into a boolean, e.g. `"true"` or `"false"`, if it's none of these values it results in a deserialization error which by default is swallowed and the property is left unset (i.e. `null`).

But I've normalized behavior in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/768d86b0e091329e9d7f97dcfc8d4d725d3b40a2) so only conventional values like `true`, `1`, `t`, `Y`, `on` deserializes to **true** and their contra values `false`, `0`, `f`, `N`, `off` deserializes to **false**  and all other values tries to deserialize to a boolean (i.e. True/False) and will result in a deserialization error if fails.

This change is available from v5.1.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: There was no deserialization error in my case. "fu" was neither <2 nor one of those values and was parsed to false (instead of null). Accordingly, setting `JsConfig.ThrowOnDeserializationError = true;` did not lead to an error.

I've read the code, `length <= 2` is correct (not <2)

Comment: @a3dho3yn 2 chars and under it resolves to a bool value, false when it didn't match a true value. It now checks for specific true/false values.